# FOREIGN EXCHANGE EARNING AND OUTGO definition

Tags: foreign-exchange

I was going through the annual report of a company listed in the stock market which have mentioned their foreign exchange earning and foreign exchange outgo. The values of both changed drastically in comparison to previous years

What is the definition of foreign exchange earning and foreign exchange outgo?

The company is an exporting company which buys a product in a country and sells it in another country. If we assume the trade is happening in dollars, how does this value change if dollar value raises/drops.

Edit: Added image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bIEs.png)

Comment: Could you add the link to the annual report?

Comment: Are the values roughly the same most years?  Most companies that have some sort of currency risk hedge those risks.  So if they profit from the dollar getting stronger against the yen in terms of sales, they take out an opposite position in the foreign exchange market that benefits from the yen getting stronger against the dollar.

Comment: "If we assume the trade is happening in dollars, how does this value change if dollar value raises/drops" To quote Leonidas I, "**If.**"

Comment: Do you mind sharing the ticker, since the company is publicly traded? "Outgo" appears to be Indian terminology, meaning "the outlay of money."